# JavaScript switch-case using a condition

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I just started learning JavaScript and I have a really basic knowledge of C#.

Tried running this piece of code:

```js
var number = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:"));

switch (number) {
  case number >= 1 && number <= 9:
    alert("The number " + number + " is a single digit number.");
    break;
  case number >= 10 && number <= 99:
    alert("The number " + number + " is a two digit number.");
    break;
  case number >= 100 && number <= 999:
    alert("The number " + number + " is a three digit number.");
    break;
  case number >= 1000 && number <= 9999:
    alert("The number " + number + " is a four digit number.");
    break;
  default:
    alert("Your number has 5 or more digits.");
}
```

but it kept failing after the following:

```js
number <= 9
```

Can you guys please give me a hand here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Switch/Case are not used for conditions.

Comment: So how can you do it differently apart from using if/else? and thank you!

Comment: you can use conditions in switch case.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do it without using `if`/`else` (when that's -definitely- the right tool for the job)?

Comment: Hey David, thank you. And I only want it to learn about the rest of JavaScript's abilities as I already went over if/else.

Comment: There's no point in learning features of a language through examples these features are not built for, though.

Comment: Try using `switch(true)` as condition is to be compared with Boolean expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The switch statement does compare its argument with the values of the expressions in the cases.

In your code, it does compare the `number` with those boolean results from the cases, so it only gets in the first case when your `number` is 1 (because `1 == true`) and falls to the `default` otherwise. You could simply compare them to `true`, like

```js
switch (true) {
  case number >= 1 && number <= 9:
    alert("The number " + number + " is a single digit number.");
    break;
  case number >= 10 && number <= 99:
    alert("The number " + number + " is a two digit number.");
    break;
  case number >= 100 && number <= 999:
    alert("The number " + number + " is a three digit number.");
    break;
  case number >= 1000 && number <= 9999:
    alert("The number " + number + " is a four digit number.");
    break;
  default:
    alert("Your number has 5 or more digits.");
}
```

but it would be cleaner to use an `if-else` construct:

```js
if (number >= 1 && number <= 9)
  alert("The number " + number + " is a single digit number.");
else if (number >= 10 && number <= 99)
  alert("The number " + number + " is a two digit number.");
else if (number >= 100 && number <= 999)
  alert("The number " + number + " is a three digit number.");
else if (number >= 1000 && number <= 9999)
  alert("The number " + number + " is a four digit number.");
else 
  alert("Your number has 5 or more digits.");
```

Btw, much shorter would be

```js
var l = String(number).length;
alert(l<5
   ? "The number "+number+" is a "+[,"single","two","three","four"][number]+" digit number."
   : "Your number has 5 or more digits."
);
```

Comment: I feel that the only benefit of using a switch in this way is if you want to allow a case to waterfall into another case. Otherwise there's no performance difference from an if/else and readability takes a back seat to obscurity.

Comment: Yeah :-) The only other benefit is that it's needs the fewest changes from the current code…

Comment: Bergi, your solution works like a charm. Guessing it makes sense to tell it to check whether the arguments are true. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need switch(true) and the rest stays the same (I guess).

Answer (score 1):

What all the other answers are missing so far is the fact that you don't need all these conditions.

```
if (number >= 10000) {
    ...
} else if (number >= 1000) {
    ...
} else if (number >= 100) {
    ...
} else if (number >= 10) {
    ...
} else if (number >= 1) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Of course there are other ways, too. For this particular example, an easy way would be to use

```
var digits = (number >= 0) ? number.toString().length : 0;
```

For positive integers it will be the number of digits, for negative numbers it will simply be `0`. A switch/case statement over this number would be possible.

A `switch(true)` is terrible style. It simply isn't what a switch/case is intended for.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this way using if/else:

```
if( number >= 1 && number <= 9)
    alert("The number " + number + " is a single digit number.");
else if( number >= 10 && number <= 99)
    alert("The number " + number + " is a two digit number.");
else if( number >= 100 && number <= 999)
     alert("The number " + number + " is a three digit number.");
else if( number >= 1000 && number <= 9999)
     alert("The number " + number + " is a four digit number.");
else
     alert("Your number has 5 or more digits.");
```

Or Try using `switch(true)` as condition is to be compared with Boolean expression.

Comment: Yup, it worked for me that way earlier, tho just wanted to see other ways to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Thankyou. Please VOTE up for my answer as well. @user2628004